# JMeter receive Invalid AuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby, jmeter

I just simply want to create a UserSignIn performance testing. My Web app is using ROR to implement after pass the credential it appear that the authenticity_token can be used per individual page I have determine Parameters tab and I receive error

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#create

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

How can I pass the authenticy_token to the Sign page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`authenticity_token` is the dynamic mandatory parameter which is used in Ruby on Rails for protection from [CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks

It needs to be [correlated](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html) as any other dynamic parameter.

For details on how to bypass CSRF protection in your JMeter test check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide.

Comment: Yes I did pass as the token as argument expression to the sample however Rails still throw exception ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Comment: Eventually i turn off  protect_from_forgery with: :exception and it's all work out